# Meaning of unix v6 assembly code generated by cc compiler?

Tags: unix, cc, pdp-11

For example, below is a piece of C code and its assembly code generated by cc compiler.

```
// C code (pre K&R C)    
foo(a, b) {
    int c, d;
    c = a;
    d = b;
    return c+d;
}
// corresponding assembly code generated by cc
.global _foo
.text
_foo:
~~foo:
~a=4
~b=6
~c=177770
~d=177766
jsr r5, csv
sub $4, sp
mov 4(r5), -10(r5)
mov 6(r5), -12(r5)
mov -10(r5), r0
add -12(r5), r0
jbr L1
L1: jmp cret
```

I can understand most of the code. But I don't know what does `~~foo:` do. And where do the magic numbers come from in `~c=177770` and `~d=177766`. The hardware is pdp-11/40.

Comment: Uninitialized variables?

Comment: The lines beginning with `~` might be comments.  Looking at "Lions' Commentary on UNIX 6th Edition", the assembler shown seems to use a `/` to mark comment lines, but there are no lines starting `~` to illustrate that usage.  But I am guessing and I'm not planning to go hunting for Unix V6 assembler for PDP 11/40 on the web, but there's a chance that one or more of the search engines knows where such information is available.

Comment: I think the lines beginning with `~` are used by linkers. But cannot find specific materials.

Comment: If working on the machine itself all of this is octal not hex.  If using a modern computer with the pdp11 backend on gcc that is a different story.  Look at the machine code, it is broken into 3 bit sections to make reading it in octal easier...gotta think octal to make the pdp11 easier to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tildes look like data which determines the stack usage.  You might find it helpful to recall that the pdp-11 used 16-bit integers, and that DEC preferred *octal* numbers over *hexadecimal*.

That

```
jsr r5, csv
```

is a way of making register 5 (r5) point to some data (perhaps the list of offsets).

The numbers correspond to offsets on the stack in *octal*.   The caller is assumed to do something like

- push a and b onto the stack (positive offsets)
- push the return address onto the stack (offset=0)
- possibly push other stuff in the `csv` function
- c and d are local variables (negative offsets, hence the "17777x")

That line

```
~d=177776
```

looks odd - I'd expect

```
~d=177766
```

since it should be below `c` on the stack.  The `-10` and `-12` offsets in the register operands look like they're also octal numbers.  You should be able to match up the offsets with the variables, by context.

That's just an educated guess: I adapted the jsr+r5 idiom a while back in a [text-editor](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#rt11edit).

The lines with tildes are symbol definitions.  A clue for that is in the *DECUS C Compiler Reference*, found at

```
ftp://ftp.update.uu.se/pub/pdp11/rsx/lang/decusc/2.19/005003/CC.DOC
```

which says

```
  3.3  Global Symbols Containing Radix-50 '$' and '.' 
         ______ _______ __________ ________     ___

    With  this  version  of  Decus C, it is possible to generate and
    access global symbols which contain the Radix-50  '.'  and  '$'.
    The  compiler allows identifiers to contain the Ascii '$', which
    becomes a Radix-50 '$' in the object code.  The AS assembly code
    shows  this  character as a tilde (~).  The underscore character
    (_) in a C program  becomes  a  '.'  in  both  the  AS  assembly
    language  and  in  the  object  code.  This allows C programs to
    access all global symbols:  

            extern int $dsw;  
            .  .  .  
            printf("Directive status = %06o\n", $dsw);  

    The  above  prints  the current contents of the task's directive
    status word.
```

So you could read

```
~a=4
```

as

```
$a=4
```

and see that **`$a`** is a (more or less) conventional symbol.

Comment: Yes, `~d=177766`. It is a negative offset, I should have thought about that. Thank you for your brilliant guess.

Comment: If I answered your question well enough, you might mark it "Accept".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. But can you share more about the tildes?